# *p or *t doesn't get applied in accept attribute of Input tag in Angular

Tags: html, file, validation, input, file-type

I am trying for users to be able to view only those file types or extensions that I specify in accept attribute of Input tag. Like in below screenshot. [FileTypes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ONQv.png)

I am providing

```
<input
                type="file"
                class="file-input"
                accept=".bks, .wka, .t21, .t22, .t23, *.p??"
                />
```

I also want binary files which are having extension .p21 or .p22 or .p23 etc. Numbers after letter p are dynamic and depend upon the year.
So when I give *.p in accept attribute, it doesn't take. I have to type manually .p21,.p22,.p23,.p24 which doesn't feel like a good solution as we have to keep adding more after few years.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have edited the question. Hope it's understandable now